# Java3D Error: Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, java-3d

This is the code in Java 3D:

```
import com.sun.j3d.utils.applet.MainFrame;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.ColorCube;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import javafx.scene.transform.Transform;
import javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D;
import javax.media.j3d.BranchGroup;
import javax.media.j3d.Transform3D;
import javax.media.j3d.TransformGroup;
import javax.vecmath.Vector3f;

class Esercizio3dot1 extends Applet {

    public Esercizio3dot1() {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Transform3D t = new Transform3D();
        GraphicsConfiguration config = SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration();
        Canvas3D canvas = new Canvas3D(config);        
        add("Center", canvas);
        BranchGroup scene = CreateSceneGraph();
        scene.compile();
        SimpleUniverse universe = new SimpleUniverse(canvas);

        universe.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
        universe.addBranchGraph(scene);

    }

    public BranchGroup CreateSceneGraph() {

        BranchGroup bg = new BranchGroup();
        TransformGroup tg = CreateSubGraph();
        bg.addChild(tg);
        return bg;
    }

    public TransformGroup CreateSubGraph() {

        TransformGroup tg = new TransformGroup();
        tg.addChild(new ColorCube(0.3));
        return tg;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("sun.awt.noerasebackground", "true");
        new MainFrame(new Esercizio3dot1(), 300, 300);

    }

}
```

The code is compiled correctly but when I run the console i produces an error (image), how could I solve it?

[image: error]

I installed the latest version of 3d java but the situation has not changed, the error is displayed equally.

Answer (score 0):

At first, Java3D and JavaFX 3D are two distinct and incompatible libraries, that's why you should remove `import javafx.scene.transform.Transform;`.

Secondly, there is no need to "install" Java3D, it's a Java library composed of JARs and those JARs have to be in your classpath like for most third party Java libraries. I advise you to read [my very detailed tutorial](http://gouessej.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/java-3d-est-de-retour-java-3d-is-back/), it explains how to use Java3D 1.6.0 and 1.7.0.

Your source code is compatible with Java3D 1.6.0 but not with Java3D 1.7.0 as the packages have been renamed in this version as it's not under Oracle's control (then it can't use the "javax" term).

Comment: But if the same code I do it in an IDE it works perfectly without failing.

Comment: I removed import javafx.scene.transform.Transform;

Comment: You didn't use the class javafx.scene.transform.Transform anyway, the import was completely useless. An IDE is a tool that can help you to become more productive when you understand how it works, keep in mind that your IDE and your program use different classpaths. Your IDE builds the classpath from the settings of the project. If you want to execute your program outside of your IDE, you have to set the classpath correctly. Maybe your IDE and your program don't use the same JRE. I advise you to read my tutorial and to avoid putting JARs into jre/lib/ext.

Comment: Unfortunately, your guide did not help me. I did not understand how it is done.

Comment: At first, you have to download those JARs: https://gouessej.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/java-3d-est-de-retour-java-3d-is-back/#download Then, you have to run your program with this command line: https://gouessej.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/java-3d-est-de-retour-java-3d-is-back/#commandline Please let me know what you tried, what failed and what worked. Please be accurate. If you don't give me any information, I won't be able to help you. This official Java3D user's guide is correct. If it doesn't work for you, you'll be the only one to blame as it works for sure.